# SQL Server CLR Integration enlisting in current transaction

Tags: sql-server, transactions, sqlclr

I'm trying to use CLR integration in SQL Server to handle accessing external files instead of storing them internally as BLOBs.  I'm trying to figure out the pattern I need to follow to make my code enlist in the current SQL transaction.  I figured I would start with the simplest scenario, deleting an existing row, since the insert/update scenarios would be more complex.

```
[SqlProcedure]
public static void DeleteStoredImages(SqlInt64 DocumentID)
{
    if (DocumentID.IsNull)
        return;

    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
    {
        conn.Open();

        string FaceFileName, RearFileName;
        int Offset, Length;
        GetFileLocation(conn, DocumentID.Value, true,
            out FaceFileName, out Offset, out Length);
        GetFileLocation(conn, DocumentID.Value, false,
            out RearFileName, out Offset, out Length);

        new DeleteTransaction().Enlist(FaceFileName, RearFileName);

        using (var comm = conn.CreateCommand())
        {
            comm.CommandText = "DELETE FROM ImagesStore WHERE DocumentID = " + DocumentID.Value;
            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}

private class DeleteTransaction : IEnlistmentNotification
{
    public string FaceFileName { get; set; }
    public string RearFileName { get; set; }
    public void Enlist(string FaceFileName, string RearFileName)
    {
        this.FaceFileName = FaceFileName;
        this.RearFileName = RearFileName;
        var trans = Transaction.Current;
        if (trans == null)
            Commit(null);
        else
            trans.EnlistVolatile(this, EnlistmentOptions.None);
    }
    public void Commit(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        if (FaceFileName != null && File.Exists(FaceFileName))
        {
            File.Delete(FaceFileName);
        }
        if (RearFileName != null && File.Exists(RearFileName))
        {
            File.Delete(RearFileName);
        }
    }

    public void InDoubt(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
    }

    public void Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment)
    {
        preparingEnlistment.Prepared();
    }

    public void Rollback(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
    }
}
```

When I actually try to run this, I get the following exception:

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user defined routine or aggregate 'DeleteStoredImages': 
System.Transactions.TransactionException: The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction. ---> System.Transactions.TransactionPromotionException: MSDTC on server 'BD009' is unavailable. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: MSDTC on server 'BD009' is unavailable.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
   at System.Data.SqlServer.Internal.StandardEventSink.HandleErrors()
   at System.Data.SqlServer.Internal.ClrLevelContext.SuperiorTransaction.Promote()
System.Transactions.TransactionPromotionException: 
   at System.Data.SqlServer.Internal.ClrLevelContext.SuperiorTransaction.Promote()
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStatePSPEOperation.PSPEPromote(InternalTransaction tx)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateDelegatedBase.EnterState(InternalTransaction tx)
System.Transactions.TransactionException: 
   at System.Transactions.TransactionState.EnlistVolatile(InternalTransaction tx, IEnlistmentNotification enlistmentNotification, EnlistmentOptions enlistmentOptions, Transaction atomicTransaction)
   at System.Transactions.TransactionStateSubordinateActive.EnlistVolatile(InternalTransaction tx, IEnlistmentNotification enlistmentNotification, EnlistmentOptions enlistmentOptions, Transaction atomicTransaction)
   at System.Transactions.Transaction.EnlistVolatile(IEnlistmentNotification enlistmentNotification, EnlistmentOptions enlistmentOptions)
   at ExternalImages.StoredProcedures.DeleteTransaction.Enlist(String FaceFileName, String RearFileName)
   at ExternalImages.StoredProcedures.DeleteStoredImages(SqlInt64 DocumentID)
. User transaction, if any, will be rolled back.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong, or point me to an example of how to do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have hopefully solved this by now, but in case anyone else has a similar problem: the error message you are getting suggests that you need to start the *Distributed Transaction Coordinator* service on the `BD009` machine (presumably your own machine).

Comment: Thanks, I actually ended up abandoning the whole thing for now because of a variety of issues (this being just one of them), but if I ever revisit this problem, knowing about the Distributed Transaction Coordinator could provide a useful starting place.

Answer (score 0):

@Aasmund's answer regarding the `Distributed Transaction Coordinator` might solve the stated problem, but that still leaves you in a non-ideal state: You are tying a transaction, which locks the `ImagesStore` table (even if it is just a `RowLock`), to two file system operations? And you need to `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` the transaction outside of this function (since that isn't being handled in the presented code).

I would separate those two pieces:

- Step 1: Delete the row from the table

  and then, IF that did not error,
- Step 2: Delete the file(s)

In the scenario where Step 1 succeeds but then Step 2, for whatever reason, fails, do one or both of the following:

- return an error status code and keep track of which `DocumentID`s got an error when attempting to delete the file in a status table. You can use that to manually delete the files and/or debug why the error occurred.
- create a process that can run periodically to find and remove unreferenced files.